# Create SAS macro to create a macro variable

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have created a SAS macro, macro A, that takes in a variable name and returns transformed versions of that name i.e. if you run `%A(asdf)` you get out `asdf_log asdf_exp asdf_10`. I want to write another macro, macro B, that takes the output from the first macro and appends it together into a new macro variable.

```
%macro B(varList, outputName);
    %let &outputName = 
        %A(var1);
        %A(var2);
        ;
%mend
```

Is almost what I want to do, except that it obviously doesn't compile.
I am also not sure if this is possible in SAS.
As a further complication, the input to macro B is a list of variable that I want to run macro A for and append into one long list of variable names.

Why? Because I have a macro that runs on a list of variables and I want to run it on a transformed variable list.

Example:
I have `%let varList = x y;` and I want as an output `x_log x_exp x_10 y_log y_exp y_10`. To do this I want two macros one, macro A, that returns the transformed variables names:

```
%macro A(var);
    &var._log
    &var._exp
    &var._10
%mend
```

I can't get the second macro (B as written above) to work properly.

Comment: Can you post some example values?  At first blush it just looks like you have too many semi-colons.

Comment: Hi Tom, yes, that won't run because of the weird placement of semi-colons. I'll give a more comprehensive example tomorrow. But, what I want is &outputName to contain the results from the running of macro A twice (or more times).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if the inner macro is just returning characters, that is it doesn't actually generate any non macro statements, then why not make the outer one work the same way?

```
%macro inner(x);
  &x._log &x._exp &x._10
%mend;

%macro outer(list);
%local i;
%do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&list));
 %inner(%scan(&list,&i))
%end;
%mend outer;

%let want=%outer(X y Z);
```

Comment: That is neater, and you are correct, as my macro doesn't actually do anything fancy, it might as well just return characters/

Answer (score 2):

This is not too hard.  You need to loop over the values in `varList`, appending results to `outputName`.  You also need to declare `outputName` as GLOBAL so it will be accessible outside `%B`

```
%macro B(varList, outputName);
%global &outputName;
%let &outputName = ;

%local i n var;
%let n = %sysfunc(countw(&varList));

%do i=1 %to &n;
   %let var = %scan(&varList,&i);
   %let &outputName = &outputName %A(&var);
%end;
%mend;
```

Comment: Thank you @DomPazz, that's what I was looking for. Setting the variable to global and adding to it like that.

Comment: You can't make a macro variable global if it already exists in some running local environment. Better to use `%if not %symexist(&outputname) %then %global &outputname;`

Comment: Also, I needed to use `%let &outputName = &&&outputName %A(&var);` to get it to correctly concatinate the list.